# AntiForgery error when calling AssemblyResolve function

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, assemblyresolve

I'm adding my own custom loader to AssemblyResolve to load some embedded resources in a .net library;

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += (sender, e) => { return Domain.Assemblies.LoadResource(e.Name, System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()); };
```

```
        public static System.Reflection.Assembly LoadResource(string fileName, System.Reflection.Assembly assembly)
        {
            fileName = assembly.GetName().Name + "." + fileName.Split(',')[0] + ".dll";
            var resFilestream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(fileName);
            byte[] ba = new byte[resFilestream.Length];
            resFilestream.Read(ba, 0, ba.Length);
            var byteArray = ba;
            resFilestream.Close();
            resFilestream.Dispose();
            return System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(byteArray);
        }
```

This works fine in many different environments(Winforms, Azure apps/webjobs/functions), but when I try to execute this code within an asp.net(4.7.2) MVC site, it breaks the anti-forgery? The issue seems to be related a DLL not being loaded correctly, and causes three seperate errors

```
TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'System.Web.Helpers.Claims.ClaimsIdentityConverter' threw an exception.
```

```
FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.IdentityModel, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. Invalid pointer (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004003 (E_POINTER))
```

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

If I remove the object initialising the class within the assembly loading dll, the site works with no error.  If I put it back in it breaks.  I also tried moving the code from the global.asax to in-line c#, but as soon as you run it, the next load of a page with a forgery token will error in the same way.

*UPDATE*
Having run Fusion++ to check the DLL loading, I can see that the DLL that is erroring actually has the exact same load failure in both situations(A fairly generic "Could not find assembly").  But only when I load my DLL does it present itself as an exception.

Comment: Tony, please, let me see if I understand: Do you change Dot Net Core code to .NET Framework? Or you use only .NET Framework (with greatter version) and downgrades your code?

Comment: You can debug the assembly loading failure by using the Fusion log. Per Scott's [Back to Basics: Using Fusion Log Viewer to Debug Obscure Loader Errors](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/back-to-basics-using-fusion-log-viewer-to-debug-obscure-loader-errors) there is a more modern tool you can use: https://github.com/awaescher/Fusion?WT.mc_id=-blog-scottha

Comment: @AntonioLeonardo No, it is just .net framework, no downgrading happening, I just wanted to illustrate that the code runs OK in every other situation.

Comment: @victor6510 When I run fusion I can see the identitymodel load event fails in both instances, but it only causes a noticeable exception when I load our Logging DLL first.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not with your code, but this dependecy Microsoft.IdentityModel: to exist this dependency and possibilty to consume into Windows client environment, probally the dll and dependecies needs to be installed at GAC (Global Assembly Cache); if Microsoft.IdentityModel not exists into GAC Folder, the code returns the error.

It's possible to install the **Windows Identity Foundation 3.5** with Visual Studio or from Windows Features install the **Windows Identity Foundation 3.5**.

Comment: The issue is that if I don't load my DLL then the identitymodel does not error in this way.  I don't want to just patch and ignore the issue, I need to work out why this is happening and fix it.

Comment: My bounty is running out, and this is actually a solution to the problem, just not the one I wanted.  Will mark as answered!